# Nearly every $x^2+y^2=z^2$ has two more solutions $x_2^2+y_2^2=z^2$ and $x_3^2+y_3^2=z^2$ is this known?

Tags: number-theory

there are $3$ distinct symbolic ways to express every $x^2+y^2=z^2$ triplet with a common z
example
$$793^2+5124^2=5185^2$$
$$935^2+5100^2=5185^2$$
$$144^2+5183^2=5185^2$$

There may be some rare situations when the $3$ distinct symbolic ways do not produce three distinct rational triplets but they are the exception.

Is this known?

EDIT
My statement was true for rationals but that is a trivial situation.  In terms of integers let me restate.

if $a^2+b^2=c^2$ then there are nearly always 3 triplets based on

$$
Z=c(3c-2a-2b)
$$

There are always 3 equations that generate but in cases like 3,4,5 being the first triplet one of the values is 0 and in very rare situations there may be non unique values.

Comment: can you illustrate with $3^2+4^2=5^2$?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking here. Is your question "is it already known that some squares [in your case, $5185^2$] are expressible as sum of squares in three ways?"?

Comment: My question regards is it known how to generate those situations given a single triplet.  I know how to do that but I don't know if its common knowledge or not.

Comment: You probably mean integer rather than rational triplets, because there are infinitely many rational solutions.

Comment: Basically you want to know which integers can be written as a sum of two squares in three or more ways and which cannot.  This reminds me a bit of Ramanujan's taxi-cab numbers, which makes me think people must have thought about this quite a bit and there must be an answer out there somewhere.

Comment: I think Fermat understood this situation.

Comment: There are more than three solutions here, e.g. $1704^2 + 4897^2= 5185^2$.  This is related to the number of ways of expressing $5185$ as the sum of two squares.

Comment: Well I meant rational but you are right about infinite.  I have a way to generate the integer cases but you can't just select any Z.  the new Z is built from old z,x,y  new Z= z*(3z-2x-2y) and there are 3 cases against it.  But the original Z may not have integer cases just rational cases which like you point out isn't interesting.

Comment: We also have two trivial additional examples: Select $x_2 = 0$, then select $y_3 = 0$.

Comment: What I am saying is given a triplet a^2+b^2=c^2 there exists another 3 Triplets where x1^2+y1^2=(c*(3c-2a-2b))^2 and x2^2+y2^2=(c*(3c-2a-2b))^2 and x3^2+y3^2=(c*(3c-2a-2b))^2 and except for 3,4,5 the cases shouldn't be trivial and the vast vast majority of them are not the same answer repeated.

Comment: Darrin please look at my answer

Comment: If you could show "nearly all" integers $z$ admit three (or more) representations of $z^2$ as the sum of two integer squares, that would be interesting.  I don't know whether it is true or not, but it's an interesting problem.

Comment: Do not deface questions.

Answer (score 4):

You can get an arbitrarily large list, take 
$$ z = 5 \cdot 13 \cdot 17 \cdots p_r,  $$
where all the primes 
$$ p_i \equiv 1 \pmod 4.  $$

Oh, as to your claim in the title, if $z \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ is prime, there is just one expression $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$ with $1 \leq x \leq y$

Next, if $z = pq$ with primes $p \neq q,$ also  $p \equiv q \equiv 1 \pmod 4,$ there are just two expressions $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$ with $1 \leq x \leq y$

Comment: What is your guess about the density of such integers (whose squares admit three or more distinct sums of squares)?

Comment: I was initially thinking rational solutions which isn't interesting.  It is correct that integer solutions are constrained to z values equal to c(3c-2a-2b) where a^2+b^2=c^2 and apparently doesn't occur with the prime numbers of the form 4#+1

Comment: Greater than 99% density of the limited conditions posted below and may be provable but I just missed that rational solutions are not interesting so take that with a grain of salt.   There are 3 distinct symbolic equations based on a^2+b^2=c^2 to generate separate x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3 with a common z123= c(3c-2b-2a) and the only way they are not distinct is if the equations happen to give the same integer for x1,x2,x3 which appears very rare but the Z=c(3c-2a-2b) may be a small subset of all possible integer Z values

Comment: @hardmath the relevant things i know are indirect, but could be adapted to this. Primes (1 mod 4) up to a bound $x$ are half $x / \log x.$ Not entirely sure about products of two primes. All numbers that can be primitively represented ($\gcd(u,v) = 1$) as $u^2 + v^2,$ meaning not divisible by $4$ or by any prime $r \equiv 3 \pmod 4,$ are $C X / \sqrt {\log x},$ where $C$ is a constant someone told me in a question of mine.  Put together, the numbers with three or more expressions are dense ***among the numbers that are primitively represented by $u^2 + v^2.$***

Comment: Consider 13719^2+37660^2=40081^2 & 10281^2+38740^2=40081^2 and 3600^2+39919^2=40081^2 where 40081 is made up of 149*269 .  Is it true that all solutions will include a prime of the form 4#+1?

Answer (score 1):

Easy to see:
$$13^2 + 84^2 = 85^2,$$
$$11^2 + 60^2 = 61^2.$$
Multiplying the first equality in $61^2$, and the second by $85^2$:
$$\boxed{793^2 + 5124^2 = 5185^2}$$
$$\boxed{935^2 + 5100^2 = 5185^2}$$
Known Brahmagupta identity:
$$(a^2 + b^2) (c^2 + d^2) = (ac + bd)^2 + (ad - bc)^2$$
$$(a^2 + b^2) (c^2 + d^2) = (ac - bd)^2 + (ad + bc)^2.$$
Substuting $a=13, b=84, c=11, d=60:$
$$(13^2 + 84^2) (11^2 + 60^2) = (13*11 + 84*60)^2 + (13*60 - 11*84)^2$$
$$(13^2 + 84^2) (11^2 + 60^2) = (13*11 - 84*60)^2 + (13*60 + 11*84)^2.$$
$$\boxed{5185^2 = 5183^2 + 144^2}$$
$$\boxed{5185^2 = 4897^2 + 1704^2}$$
Thus, we have 4 of identity and a clear process for their preparation.

Using $a=3,b=4, c=5, d=12,$ have:
$$\boxed{39^2+52^2=65^2}$$
$$\boxed{25^2+60^2=65^2}$$
$$\boxed{63^2+16^2=65^2}$$
$$\boxed{33^2+56^2=65^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT.- Besides the well known Pythagorean identity $$(x^2-y^2)^2+(2xy)^2=(x^2+y^2)^2$$ you have also the following less known identity $$(mt+ns)^2+(ms-nt)^2=(mt-ns)^2+ms+nt)^2$$ where $m,n,t,s$ are arbitrary.

I think that, associating $x,y$ with $m,n,t,s$ you can maybe find out examples with more than three distinct "Pytagorean triangles with the same hypotenuse". Good luck.

Comment: Ataulfo thanks I have never seen that one before. I am using (a+c)^2+(b+c)^2=(a+b+c)^2 and the inverse (a-c)^2+(b-c)^2=(a+b-c)^2 where 2 a b=c^2

Comment: You are welcome, Darrin. Good luck in your search of, say, four triangles. An interesting point for you could be a bound for the possibilities but this could require a proof. Is $3$ this possible bound?